# CPU threads state in OSX Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, cpu, system-information

I need info of each CPU's thread load in OSX Terminal.

And is there any way to see exect thread load?

PS: I saw Activity Monitor -> Window -> CPU Usage.

Comment: have you check `top`  check the examples on the man page, probably can help `top -o cpu -O +rsize -s 5 -n 20`

Comment: Top - shows only summary info.

Comment: Thanks Jay, link helped!

To install Brew on mac os Sierra you need to use this code `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`
Than install htop: `brew install htop`